# system load spikes causing php-fpm pools to fill and cause micro outages

Tags: nginx, networking, centos, php, php-fpm

kind of at my wits end at this point and looking for some help.

### 2 physical Web servers

CentOS
NGINX
PHP5
php-fpm

### 2 physical DB Servers

CentOS
NGINX
elastic search
zookeeper
couchbase

as user load increases and the php-fpm pools fill I start to get datadog alerts that the network connections are dropping. the odd thing is that I dont see any dropped packets. During the periods that user load increases I have ping floods running across the LAN from server to server from server to outside and from outside to WAN IPs of the servers - and dont get any dropped packets during these time periods

However, when the load is high during the micro outages, commands over ssh, including ls and vim are slow to respond, but don't fail. I can bring up htop which doesn't show anything other than the load values higher than normal at the time.

Im working on setting up a zabbix server to try and catch some of these outages but Im wondering/hoping other people have some suggestions on how to catch these micro outages

Comment: Dropped packets and dropped connections are different things.

Comment: @AlexD Hi Alex, yeah I understand that, but this is the information I have to go on, if theres something else that you think would help you to suggest some pointers Id be happy to provide it